# raw_input e print em python não funcionam nas funções

Tags: python

Bom pessoal estou iniciando agora em python e tenho que criar esse projeto de um quiz que completa os espaços das frases. Mas, minha dificuldade está em entender porque os raw_inputs e print não estão funcionando dentro das funções. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?
Meu código está assim:

```
#coding = utf-8
data = {
'facil': {
    'frase': 'Chuva _1_ . _2_ . _3_ . e _4_ deitado.',
    'respostas': ['cai', 'em', 'pe', 'corre'],
    'falhas': 5
},
'medio': {
    'frase':
    'Quando falamos de Google _1_, _2_ Drive, _3_ e _4_; nos referimos a aplicativos de armazenamento em nuvem(cloud computing).\n',
    'respostas': ['Drive', 'One', 'Dropbox', 'Mega'],
    'falhas':
    2
},
'dificil': {
    'frase':
    'Sabendo que x é igual a 7 e ele segue repetindo por mais três vezes e cada repetição soma se 6 e na ultima subtrai 2, concluimos que o segundo valor é: _1_, o terceiro valor é _2_, para o quarto resultamos em _3_ e para finalizar temos _4_ sendo a soma dessa sequência \n.',
    'respostas': ['13', '19', '23', '62'],
    'falhas':
    0
 }
}
def nivel():
while True:
  nivel = raw_input('Escolha entre o nivel facil, medio e dificil').lower()
  if nivel in data:
        return nivel
  print 'Esse nivel nao existe tente novamente'


def jogada(nivel): # Ao digitar o nivel ele é passado para essa função
frase = data[nivel]['frase']
chances = data[nivel]['falhas']
index = 0

  while index <len(data[nivel]['respostas']) and chances >=0:
     print frase
     respostas = raw_input(['frase']+str(index + 1 +'\n')).lower()
  if respostas == data[nivel]['respostas']:
     print 'Correto.'
     frase = frase.replace(str(index +1)).data[nivel]['repostass'][index] #Troca os espaços em brancos por palavra digitadas se forem corretas
```

Comment: Algum erro é apresentado?

Comment: Nenhum erro, apenas não mostra nenhuma informação.

Comment: Este é todo o seu programa? Você definiu duas funções mas em nenhum momento as está chamando.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Você Sveen e o Giovanni Nunes me ajudaram muito, o programa começou a rodar.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa chamar as funções, o jeito mais elegante em Python é criar uma função main():

```
def main():
    nivel_escolhido = nivel()
    jogada(nivel_escolhido)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Assim tuas funções serão executadas.

Só te adiantando que há alguns erros no laço *while* da função `jogada()`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou tentar fazer desse modo.

Comment: Mas é o que tua lógica definiu, ele fica num laço até um nível válido ser inserido.

Comment: Acabei tirando o comentário anterior, desculpa. Sim, minha lógica foi definida desse modo como você disse, mas mesmo inserindo o nivel certo ele não executa outra parte do código, ficou apenas no while do nivel.

Comment: Giovanni Nunes, usei a def main como me orientou, mudei o o código para:                                                                                     
    def nivel():
    nivel = raw_input('Escolha entre o nivel facil, medio e dificil').lower()
    while True:
    if nivel in data:
      modo(nivel)
   else:
     print 'Esse nivel nao existe tente novamente'
     break
     nivel()                                                                                                       Assim resolve o problema com while por hora, mas vou resolver os outros primeiro.